Family reunion crossword: The case of the missing letters
This is a crossword version of the "cryptic family reunion" puzzle type introduced by Jeremy Dover. Ten thematic clues have had their definition part replaced by a term for a family member.
Due to grid size concerns, I have had to leave two letters out of this crossword that I really wanted to include. Can you guess which two letters I would have liked to add?

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Team loses grand finale on plaza (6)
6. Aunt is capturing bishop, embracing Italian opening (4)
8. EU citizen not allowed to start chant on the Santiago Bernabéu? (3)
9. Did sire note Erik's epithet? (8)
10. Villains, to protect interests, ultimately kidnapped me (6)
11. Brother is in on misery, unfortunately (5,5)
15. Dictator's fortune's indicative of great wealth (4)
17. Wrap Andrew's behind in seat (7)
18. (With wild eyes) "Or, as they say in France, au revoir!" (3,3)
20. Prison established by group such as Amnesty International in a major US city (6)
22. Cousin utilises kernel in nut (7)
24. Terms of the abdicating king: "Rhinos – they may be poached" (4)
26. Father is eccentric, accompanying eccentric Arab touring ancient city (10)
28. Unfitting choice of award for Dentist of the Year? (6)
30. I need Jon to budge as requested (8)
33. Song from rock musical; not the opener (3)
34. Harpist Clark Gomez: "Juneteenth lasts one year!" (4)
35. Grandma's game playing is interrupted by Dick (6)
Down
2. Like a uniform question that comes up (3)
3. To start with, American president has, among other things, difficulty form coherent sentences? (7)
4. Hobbit rejects outsiders for trip (3)
5. Every now and then, greet F1 official (3)
6. Shade that's covering Philippine city straddling the north side of Luzon (3,4)
7. One unassociated with major record labels after releasing one adult-rated record (5)
8. Old studies on eastern city (6)
9. Encourage to be cooler (3)
12. Approximately seven-foot man named Charles Foster was portrayed by him (6)
13. Mother's mother almost left in obscurity (7)
14. Nephew got up? Everybody up! (7)
16. Niece lifted Jafe up (3)
19. Proprietor of many casinos here has whiskey served up (5)
20. Wonder Woman's seen in empty arcade (3)
21. Unfinished quest boy failed leads to funeral ceremony (7)
22. Sister is P!nk's number one 9 down (6)
23. Beginning union leader apprehended by Shell (7)
25. Uncle heading for hotel after celebration (5)
27. Female help, not male help (3)
29. When topless, loved attention (3)
31. Difficult situation where one might play it by 29 down (3)
32. He lived in Biblical times among Israelites (3)

Clue 12D is brilliant!

GRID

 

ACROSS

 1. SQUARE = SQUA(-d) + RE [on, as in regarding]
 6. IBIS = IS capturing B embracing I_
 8. OLE = (-p)OLE
 9. FATHERED = FA [note] + THE RED
 10. FIENDS = FENDS + I
 11. NOISY MINER = (IN ON MISERY)*
 15. LUXE = "LUCKS"
 17. SWADDLE = _W in SADDLE
 20. ANGOLA = NGO in A + LA
 22. PELICAN = _LI_ in PECAN
 24. EGGS = _E _G _G _S
 26. KOOKABURRA = KOOK + ARAB* on UR
 28. PLAQUE [not sure how to characterize it]
 30. ENJOINED = (I NEED JON)*
 33. AIR = (-h)AIR
 34. ZHAY = _Z _H + A + Y
 35. MAGPIE = GAME* + PI [private investigator]

DOWN

 2. QUA [like, as in as] = (A + U [NATO] + Q)<
 3. APHASIA = A_ P_ + HAS + IA [inter alia]
 4. ERR = (-m)ERR(-y)
 5. REF = gReEt F1
 6. ICE BLUE = IE covering CEBU on L_
 7. INDEX = IND(-i)E + X
 8. ODENSE = O + DENS + E
 9. FAN (ddef.)
 12. ORSON = OR SO [approximately] + _N [seven-foot]
 13. MUDLARK = MU(-m) + L in DARK
 14. ROSELLA = ROSE + ALL<
 16. EMU = ME< + U
 18. SEE YOU = EYES* + OU [or in French]
 19. OWNER = (RENO has W [NATO])<
 20. AWE = W in A_E
 21. OBSEQUY = (QUES_ + BOY)*
 22. PLOVER = P_ + LOVER
 23. CAUSING = U_ in CASING
 25. GALAH = H_ after GALA
 27. AID = (-m)AID
 29. EAR = (-d)EAR
 31. JAM (ddef.)
 32. ELI = israELItes

FAMILY REUNION

 All family reunion clues refer to Australian birds:
 6A - IBIS
 11A - NOISY MINER
 22A - PELICAN
 26A - KOOKABURRA
 35A - MAGPIE
 13D - MUDLARK
 14D - ROSELLA
 15D - EMU
 22D - PLOVER
 25D - GALAH

EXTRA LETTERS

 Instead of FATHERED FIENDS, it would have been nice to write FEATHERED FRIENDS!

